# Combining specific column of elements in an environment with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have downloaded stock data for the health care stocks of the S&P500 into a separate environment, now I would like to grab the Adjusted close column from each element of the environment and combine them into one data frame. I have written the following but I get an error:

```
   require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(PortfolioAnalytics)

#environment where stocks data will be saved
stocks_environment <- new.env()

#day to start downloading the data from
start_date <- "2020-01-01"

#create vectors containing the sector relevant tickers from the S&P500 and download the data
health_care_sector <- c("A",    "ABBV", "ABC",  "ABMD", "ABT",  "ALGN", "ALXN", "AMGN", "ANTM", "BAX",  "BDX",  "BIIB", "BMY",  "BSX",  "CAH",  "CERN", "CI",   "CNC",  "COO",  "CVS",  "DGX",  "DHR",  "DVA",  "EW",   "GILD", "HCA",  "HOLX", "HSIC", "HUM",  "IDXX", "ILMN", "INCY", "IQV",  "ISRG", "JNJ",  "LH",   "LLY",  "MCK",  "MDT",  "MRK",  "MTD",  "MYL",  "PFE",  "PKI",  "PRGO", "REGN", "RMD",  "STE",  "SYK",  "TFX",  "TMO",  "UHS",  "UNH",  "VAR",  "VRTX", "WAT",  "XRAY", "ZBH",  "ZTS")
health_care_sector_names <- c("Agilent Technologies",   "Abbvie Inc",   "Amerisourcebergen Corp",   "Abiomed Inc",  "Abbott Laboratories",  "Align Technology", "Alexion Pharm Inc",    "Amgen Inc",    "Anthem Inc",   "Baxter International Inc", "Becton Dickinson and Company", "Biogen Inc",   "Bristol-Myers Squibb Company", "Boston Scientific Corp",   "Cardinal Health",  "Cerner Corp",  "Cigna Corp",   "Centene Corp", "Cooper Companies", "CVS Corp", "Quest Diagnostics Inc",    "Danaher Corp", "Davita Healthcare Partners Inc",   "Edwards Lifesciences Corp",    "Gilead Sciences Inc",  "Hca Holdings Inc", "Hologic Inc",  "Henry Schein Inc", "Humana Inc",   "Idexx Laboratories",   "Illumina Inc", "Incyte Corp",  "Iqvia Holdings Inc",   "Intuitive Surg Inc",   "Johnson & Johnson",    "Laboratory Corp of America Holdings",  "Eli Lilly and Company",    "Mckesson Corp",    "Medtronic Inc",    "Merck & Company",  "Mettler-Toledo International", "Mylan NV Ord Shs", "Pfizer Inc",   "Perkinelmer",  "Perrigo Company",  "Regeneron Pharmaceuticals",    "Resmed Inc",   "Steris Corp",  "Stryker Corp", "Teleflex Inc", "Thermo Fisher Scientific Inc", "Universal Health Services",    "Unitedhealth Group Inc",   "Varian Medical Systems",   "Vertex Pharmaceutic",  "Waters Corp",  "Dentsply Sirona Inc",  "Zimmer Biomet Holdings",   "Zoetis Inc Cl A")
getSymbols(health_care_sector,from = start_date,env = stocks_environment)


number_of_rows <- nrow(stocks_environment$A)
number_of_columns <- length(health_care_sector)
health_care_matrix <- matrix(nrow = number_of_rows,ncol = number_of_columns)
colnames(health_care_matrix) <- health_care_sector_names

#combine all the adjusted closing prices for each stock in the stockenvironment into one matrix 
for(i in health_care_sector){
  x <- get(i,envir = stocks_environment)[,6]["2020/"]
  start <- 1
  health_care_matrix[,start] <- x
  start <- start+1
}
```

I don't get an error before I get to the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note you have the start counter inside the for loop resetting the counter to 1. 
Code worked after fixing that.

```
start <- 1
for(i in health_care_sector){
  x <- get(i,envir = stocks_environment)[,6]["2020/"]
  print(head(x))
  health_care_matrix[,start] <- x
  start <- start+1
}
```

Comment: Thanks newb, realised this when I was talking to you on discord. Embarrassing.